# How can I copy the members of nested structs to a CUDA device's memory space?

Tags: visual-c++, cuda, nested, device, struct

I'm trying to copy some nested structs to device memory for kernel use in a CUDA-accelerated neural network simulator. This code links and runs, but it throws some exceptions and CUDA errors:

```
typedef struct rdLayer
{
    long NeuronQty ;
    long DendriteQty ;

    cuDoubleComplex *gpuWeights ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuZOutputs ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuDeltas ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuUnWeights ;
} rdLayer;

typedef struct rdNetwork
{
    long SectorQty;
    double K_DIV_TWO_PI;
    double two_pi_div_sect_qty;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuSectorBdry;
    long LayerQty;
    rdLayer *rLayer;
} rdNetwork;

struct rdLearningSet 
{
    long EvalMode ;
    long SampleQty ;
    long InputQty ;
    long OutputQty ;
    long ContOutputs ;
    long SampleIdxReq ;

    cuDoubleComplex *gpuXInputs ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuDOutputs ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuYOutputs ;
    double *gpudSE1024 ;
    cuDoubleComplex *gpuOutScalar ;
};

[...]
    struct rdLearningSet * rdLearn;
    struct rdNetwork * rdNet;
[...]
    cudaMalloc(&rdNet, sizeof(rdNetwork));
    cudaMalloc(&rdLearn, sizeof(rdLearningSet));
[...]
    cuDoubleComplex * dummy;
    struct rdLayer rdlSource, * rdldummy;
[...]
    //rdLayer *rLayer;
    cudaMalloc(&rdldummy, sizeof(rdLayer)*rSes.rNet->LayerQty);
    cudaMemcpy( &rdNet->rLayer, &rdldummy, sizeof(rdLayer*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for (int L=1; L<rSes.rNet->LayerQty; L++){
            // construct layer to be copied
            rdlSource.NeuronQty=rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iNeuronQty 
            rdlSource.DendriteQty=rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iDendriteQty 
            cudaMalloc( &rdlSource.gpuWeights, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].DendriteQty+1) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].NeuronQty+1) ) 
                    mCheckCudaWorked
            cudaMalloc( &rdlSource.gpuZOutputs, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].DendriteQty+1) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].NeuronQty+1) ) 
                    mCheckCudaWorked
            cudaMalloc( &rdlSource.gpuDeltas, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iDendriteQty+1) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iNeuronQty+1) ) 
                    mCheckCudaWorked
            cudaMalloc( &rdlSource.gpuUnWeights, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iDendriteQty+1) * (rSes.rNet->rLayer[L].iNeuronQty+1) ) 
                    mCheckCudaWorked
            //copy layer sructure to Device mem
            cudaMemcpyToSymbol( "rdNet->rLayer", &rdlSource, sizeof(rdLayer), sizeof(rdLayer) * L, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );/*! 2D neuron cx weight matrix on GPU */
                    mCheckCudaWorked
    }
[...]   
    cudaMalloc(&dummy, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rLearn->SampleQty) * (rSes.rLearn->InputQty+1) ); /*! 2D complex input tuples in GPU. */
            cudaMemcpy( &rdLearn->gpuXInputs, &dummy, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
                    cudaMemcpy( &dummy, &rSes.rLearn->gpuXInputs, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rLearn->SampleQty) * (rSes.rLearn->InputQty+1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
                    mCheckCudaWorked        
    cudaMalloc(&dummy, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rLearn->SampleQty) * (rSes.rLearn->OutputQty+1) ); /*! 2D desired complex outputs in GPU. */
            cudaMemcpy( &rdLearn->gpuDOutputs, &dummy, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
                    cudaMemcpy( &dummy, &rSes.rLearn->gpuDOutputs, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * (rSes.rLearn->SampleQty) * (rSes.rLearn->OutputQty+1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
                    mCheckCudaWorked
[...]
```

Unfortunately, the cudaMemcpyToSymbol call returns an error that the mCheckCudaWorked macro says is "invalid device symbol", while the last (cudaMemcpy( &dummy, &rSes.rLearn->gpuDOutputs...) and third-from-last (cudaMemcpy( &dummy, &rSes.rLearn->gpuXInputs...) cudaMemcpy calls return "invalid argument".

I am at a loss as to how to proceed to get these items copied to device memory and addressable from kernel code. &dummy and &rdldummy are positively being returned as the pointers to the device memory addresses where the allocated memory awaits, and I can write those pointers to the device memory, but I cannot coax the bulk of the member values into being copied to the pointed-at allocations. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields like `gpuXInputs` need to be point at memory which has been allocated with `cudaMalloc`, so that they are valid pointers to *device memory*.

Typically you need a host version of your data structures, where your allocations use `malloc` etc, and then a mirror of these data structures on the device, which have been allocated via `cudaMalloc`. Any pointers within these data structures need to point to the right kind of memory - you can't "mix and match".

Comment: That is what I am attempting; I cudaMalloc enough device memory for a rdLearningSet struct, and store the pointer to that in rdLEarn. Then I cudaMalloc enough device memory to hold the so-many sets of input coordinates, and store the pointer to that in the device memory location rdLrean->gpuXInputs. This seems to work correctly. But when I try to copy that block of cordinate sets to the destination of the pointer stored as rdLearn->gpuXInputs, no go!

Comment: rdlSource is where I build a duplicate structure to copy over.
I don't see where I am mixing the pointer types in the structures, can you point that out?

Comment: Not easy to debug from just these code framgments - I suggest you take a "divide and conquer" approach until you have a smaller problem

Comment: I noticed that the supplied examples in the CUDA C PDF use cudaMalloc ((void**)&varname, ... but cudaMemcpy(varname, ... when it comes to copying. Removing the address operator in the problem lines of the above code let me copy the arrays of values. Oddly enough, the singular values still verfiably copy over and back with the & in place.